# Application that is able to edit FLAC files

Tags: software-rec, flac, sound-editing

Does anyone know one? If possible free, or at least not so expensive as Adobe Audition :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/) is a multi-platform [F/OSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open_source_software) sound editor that will edit .flac files.

Comment: Always +1 for Audacity. Note that FLAC only comes in Audacity's Beta.

Answer (score 2):

Just glancing around I found [Total Recorder](http://www.totalrecorder.com/index.htm) which seems to support flac files.  It doesn't look like it has incredibly sophisticated editing tools, but I don't know what you're looking for in that regard.  Looks like there is a demo that you can try out.